# DB2 Conection (Linux) CLI 10.5 - Hangs

Tags: linux, db2, command-line-interface, freeze

We are having an issue with the DB2 connection is successful yet hangs -- no errors nor does code continue to the next line of execution.....broke this down to just running the CLI to perform a basic validate and it shows the same symptom.

```
    dsadmin@usc1:/opt/ibm/clidriver/bin$ db2cli writecfg add -database DBNAME -host 10.0.0.444 -port 9470 -parameter "SecurityTransportMode=SSL"
    dsadmin@usc1:/opt/ibm/clidriver/bin$ db2cli validate -dsn MAX_DEV -connect -user UID -passwd PWD

    ===============================================================================
    Client information for the current copy:
    ===============================================================================

    Client Package Type       : IBM Data Server Driver For ODBC and CLI
    Client Version (level/bit): DB2 v10.5.0.5 (special_33523/64-bit)
    Client Platform           : Linux/X8664
    Install/Instance Path     : /opt/ibm/clidriver
    DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH value: <not-set>
    db2dsdriver.cfg Path      : /opt/ibm/clidriver/cfg/db2dsdriver.cfg
    DB2CLIINIPATH value       : <not-set>
    db2cli.ini Path           : /opt/ibm/clidriver/cfg/db2cli.ini
    db2diag.log Path          : /opt/ibm/clidriver/db2dump/db2diag.log

    ===============================================================================
    db2dsdriver.cfg schema validation for the entire file:
    ===============================================================================

    Success: The schema validation completed successfully without any errors.

    ===============================================================================
    The output of the validate command ends with the "Success" message however does not return to command line....hangs....


    ===========================DB2 CLI TRACE==================================
    dsadmin@usc1:/opt/ibm/clidriver/bin$ vi 'clitrace;'
    [ db2cli.ini Location:       /opt/ibm/clidriver/cfg/db2cli.ini ]
    [ db2dsdriver.cfg Location:  /opt/ibm/clidriver/cfg/db2dsdriver.cfg ]
    [ CLI Driver Type:           IBM Data Server Driver For ODBC and CLI ]



    SQLAllocEnv( phEnv=<NULL pointer> )
        ---> Time elapsed - 0 seconds

    SQLAllocEnv( )
        <--- SQL_ERROR   Time elapsed - +1.100000E-005 seconds

    SQLAllocEnv( phEnv=&00007ffd94147934 )
        ---> Time elapsed - +3.130975E+001 seconds

    SQLAllocEnv( phEnv=0:1 )
        <--- SQL_SUCCESS   Time elapsed - +1.780000E-004 seconds

    SQLFreeEnv( hEnv=0:1 )
        ---> Time elapsed - +2.500000E-005 seconds

    SQLFreeEnv( )
        <--- SQL_SUCCESS   Time elapsed - +2.100000E-005 seconds

    ================END OF FILE==================================
```

Comment: You write "connection is successful yet hangs", but you show no evidence of connect. I suspect your SSL Db2 client config. Schema validation alone does not connect. The db2cli output and clitrace fragment shows no SQLConnect. Prove first that the connection succeeds *without SSL*. To get more specific help, Give more facts, exactly which components/versions/configuration-steps, which distro, target Db2-platform (z/os, i-series, LUW etc) ,how you've configured your keystore etc.

Comment: Environment information: 

AWS/RHEL7.x -> Firewall -> F5/Proxy -> Firewall -> AS400/DB2

Firewall rules, proxy configuration, static routes in place to support round trip messaging via SSL. SSL is required.

Comment: you did not respond to the main point: no evidence of connect in either db2cli output or  cli trace . Also no details of  SSL config at db2 client level.

Comment: So - evidence of a connect is the issue -- it is hanging at that point -- wording prior is incorrect as the trace log shows a 'CONNECT' didn't happen....traffic is going back/forth per network trace.

The SSL configuration is not known -- on other systems we use the IBM DB2 ODBC driver (iseries 7) and check the box on SSL -- no other configuration needed.

It would seem some form of error or something would be returned if the keys or other items don't align -- this is just hanging/blocking.....no response

Comment: If you can edit your question to clarify, it would be better. Can you clarify exactly which IBM components you've installed on the Linux client?

Comment: The Linux box has Client Version (level/bit): DB2 v10.5.0.5 (special_33523/64-bit)

Comment: If you are not using 'IBM i access for Linux' don't you need to communicate via a Db2-connect server , or have you a licence file for Db2-connect installed on Linux also?